# Excel macro sometimes incredibly slow in Excel 2016, but not in Excel 2010 (High CPU usage)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user (and his colleagues) who's macro that worked flawlessly in Excel 2010 suddenly doesn't work very well in Excel 2016, the macro will sometimes result in very high CPU usage (CPU goes from 12% to 66+%), making it incredibly slow and non responding.

The kicker is that it works fine to begin with, but when they've run the macro once or twice or done x amount of work in a different spreadsheet, the problem will occur.

I can't disclose the code as it's sensitive data and I'm part of an external support service, but I can tell you that they do protect/unprotect the document and there are SQL transactions going on.

The problem occurs after (depending on how the code is executed) the document protection is removed,- it seems to be when an InputBox is shown that Excel goes to crap. One can enter letters, but they will only show up after x amount of seconds.

Is it a known thing that certain methods don't work as well in 2016 as it does in 2010, or does 2016 generally not perform as well as 2010.

Do we need to change the code, or is there something that can be done via Excel settings?

Comment: Yes change the code, write new code- good luck

Comment: From 12% to 66+% ? Sounds like one or more of the queries is running..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Protect and UnProtect methods in Excel 2013 and 2016 are more than 2000 times (!) slower than in 2010 and before, due to the new password hash algorithm the newer versions use. Omitting the password altogether resolves that issue, but isn't always a good solution.

Alternatively, make sure that on opening of the file (when first needed) the worksheets are protected using the UserInterfaceOnly set to true and stay away from protecting/unprotecting from then onwards.

Comment: Very good knowledge jkp. Is this from one of your speed tests, or do you have a source? I am finding that Excel 2010 seems best for a lot of things, and the newer versions really struggle with what I consider mainstream tasks. Is this on your website?

Comment: This is from speed tests with client files. I wouldn't say 2010 is "best" for a lot of things, each version of Excel has its pro's and cons.